# Qt/C++ Как "перевернуть" строку по вертикали?

Tags: c++, qt

Делаю график на Qt. Нужно подписать координатную ось ОY. Ось ОX подписал правильно, слева направо от меньшего к большему. Ось ОY подписать тоже удалось но значения идут "сверху" "вниз", в общем вот скриншот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А нужно, чтобы `0.5` было около `0`. Можно ли как-то это реализовать? "Перевернуть" строку может быть. Не уверен, что фраза "зеркально отразить" тут подходит. 
Подписываю оси так:

В заголовочном файле:

```
QGraphicsTextItem *X;
QGraphicsTextItem *ZeroX;

double xmin;
double dx;
double xmax;
```

В файле .сpp

```
 int n =16;

 // Отступы сетки

int gdx = (graphicsScene->width())/n;
int gdy = (graphicsScene->height())/n;

  // Переменные графика
  xmin = 0.0;
  xmax = 2.0;
  dx = 0.05;

 // Надписи на ОХ
for (int i =2; i<n;i++){
    graphicsScene->addText(QString::number((xmin + (i-1)*dx*10)))-> 
    setPos((graphicsScene->width()/n)*i-graphicsScene-> 
    width()/pow(n,3),graphicsScene->height()-2*n);
    }
X = new QGraphicsTextItem ("X", 0,0);
X->setPos (graphicsScene->width()-n, graphicsScene->height()-2*n);
graphicsScene->addItem(X);

ZeroX = new QGraphicsTextItem ("0", 0,0);
ZeroX->setPos (2*n, graphicsScene->height()-2*n);

graphicsScene->addItem(ZeroX);

// Подписи на ОY

for (int i =n; i>1-1;i--){
    graphicsScene->addText(QString::number((xmin + i*dx*10)))->setPos(n/2,(graphicsScene->width()/n)*i-graphicsScene->width()/pow(n,3));

}
```

Comment: проблема точно связана с тем, что координаты монитора начинаются с левого верхнего угла, но я не могу понять где у вас подписи осей добавляются)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не тянет на ответ,  но попробуйте в подписях для OY сделать xmax-i*dx*10 вместо xmin+....

Comment: Тогда изменятся значения надписей, а мне нужно просто начать со значения 7 и закончить значениям 0.5))

Comment: А что мешает начать с 0.5 и закончить на 7?

Comment: Так графики не подписывают.. Отсчет ведется от нуля. Около нуля должен быть 0+шаг масштаба и так далее.

Comment: Спасибо,  я в курсе :)) но у Вас получается последняя надпись,  7, выводится около нуля.  Почему,  сохранив порядок вывода на график надписей,  не изменить порядок строк в этих надписях?

Comment: У Вас вывод надписей начинается с верхнего конца оси. Ну так выведите туда 7.5, что вам мешает??

Comment: Я Вас не совсем понял... как можно изменить "Порядок строк в надписях"? И что вы имеете в виду под этим понятием?

Comment: Вывод начинается с верхнего конца оси,  так?

Comment: Вы первой выводите строку "0", и она попадает на верхний конец оси. Последней Вы выводите "7.5", он попадает в начало координат. Так выведите первой строкой не  0, а 7.5, и тогда на верхний конец попадет 7.5, а к началу координат - 0

Comment: Я не знаю 7,5, там будет или какое-то другое число. Все зависит от переменной n Да и к тому же если я ввиду 7,5 в цикл, мне вверху напишет 7,5, 8...

Comment: Не важно,  7.5, или n... Это абсолютно не имеет значения.

Comment: Если же говорить о том,  что будет 7.5, 8, 8.5.... Посмотрите внимательно на ту строку,  что я вам предложил в "ответе"

Comment: "Так графики не подписывают.. Отсчет ведется от нуля" не верно. Если диапазон значений лежит и 5000 до 5001, ось от нуля будет выглядеть очень глупо